# forgotten password with node and sendgride issue

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have tried to set up the forgot password backend as follows but it seems not to work.

```
exports.forgotPassword = (req, res) => {
const { email } = req.body.email;

User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            error: 'User with that email does not exist'
        });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_RESET_PASSWORD, { expiresIn: '10m' });

    // email
    const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: email,
        subject: `Password reset link`,
        html: `
        <p>Please use the following link to reset your password:</p>
        <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/password/reset/${token}</p>
        <hr />
        <p>This email may contain sensetive information</p>
        
    `
    };
    // populating the db > user > resetPasswordLink
    return user.updateOne({ resetPasswordLink: token }, (err, success) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ error: errorHandler(err) });
        } else {
            sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent => {
                return res.json({
                    message: `Email has been sent to ${email}. Follow the instructions to reset your password. Link expires in 10min.`
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

};

Test on postman showing sending without success and error

[image]

up on canceling the continues sending a request in postman, there is no error in postman console. However, my terminal console has this funny response

[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that you've not included the "next()" function after you log the request path to the console.

Comment: Please, at what portion of the code are you referring to?

Comment: @EmmanuelOga Could you please add the code where you actually use forgotPassword ?

Comment: @drip

See the route where forgotpassword is defined

router.put("/forgot-password", forgotPasswordValidator, forgotPassword);

Also the validation code

exports.forgotPasswordValidator = (req, res) => {
    req.check('email')
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('Must be a valid email address')
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since express doesn't know when to go from a function to another function, you need to call the next() argument, passed to these functions (in this case: forgotPasswordValidator and forgotPassword). You can find more on that here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

The router:

```
const validationRules = () => {
    return [
        check('email')
        .notEmpty().withMessage('Please add an email address')
        .isEmail().withMessage('Must be a valid email address')
    ]
}

router.put("/forgot-password", validationRules(), forgotPasswordValidator, forgotPassword);
```

forgotPasswordValidator middleware function:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
exports.forgotPasswordValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  } else next()
};
```

The forgotPassword function seems fine, but if you have any more problems feel free to write a comment.